# grpc and polly - .net core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, polly

I'm trying to use Polly as retry policy handler for grpc in my .net core 6 project. I noticed that the `retryFunc` is never invoked. I started from this project [gRPC & ASP.NET Core 3.1: Resiliency with Polly](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/03/31/grpc-asp-net-core-3-1-resiliency-with-polly/)

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // DI
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        });

        var serverErrors = new HttpStatusCode[] { 
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, 
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout, 
            HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, 
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
            HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests, 
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout 
        };

        var gRpcErrors = new StatusCode[] {
            StatusCode.DeadlineExceeded,
            StatusCode.Internal,
            StatusCode.NotFound,
            StatusCode.ResourceExhausted,
            StatusCode.Unavailable,
            StatusCode.Unknown
        };

        Func<HttpRequestMessage, IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>> retryFunc = (request) =>
        {
            return Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => {
                
                var grpcStatus = StatusManager.GetStatusCode(r);
                var httpStatusCode = r.StatusCode;

                return (grpcStatus == null && serverErrors.Contains(httpStatusCode)) || // if the server send an error before gRPC pipeline
                       (httpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && gRpcErrors.Contains(grpcStatus.Value)); // if gRPC pipeline handled the request (gRPC always answers OK)
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, (input) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3 + input), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
                                {
                                    var grpcStatus = StatusManager.GetStatusCode(result.Result);
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {grpcStatus}. Retry");
                                });
        };

        services.AddGrpcClient<CountryServiceClient>(o =>
        {
            o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
        }).AddPolicyHandler(retryFunc);

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var client = provider.GetRequiredService<CountryServiceClient>();

        try
        {
            var countries = (await client.GetAllAsync(new EmptyRequest())).Countries.Select(x => new Country
            {
                CountryId = x.Id,
                Description = x.Description,
                CountryName = x.Name
            }).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Found countries");
            countries.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Found country {x.CountryName} ({x.CountryId}) {x.Description}"));

        }
        catch (RpcException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

but at the end `WaitAndRetryAsync` is never called.

I created a small project available on [github](https://github.com/mserioli/PollyCheck) in order to reproduce it.

My test is fairly simple. I start the client without a listening back-end, expecting to read 3 times the output from `Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {grpcStatus}. Retry");` on the console. But the policy handler in never fired. I have the following exception instead

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to
subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
(10061): No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it.
```

without any retry.

Comment: What have you changed on Anthony's code?

Comment: Since your `retryFunc` does not uses the request you can define it like this `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryFunc() => Policy.HandleResult...` [There is an extension overload which looks for this signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Comment: changed almost nothing. just created a proto file and modified the proto service name and content, but basically everything is the same

Comment: Are you sure that it is never firing? Have you tried to set a breakpoint inside the `onRetry` delegate? Or inside the `resultPredicate`?

Comment: BTW based on the exception it seems like you have received an Http Status Code 503 (Service Unavailable), which is not listed in the `serverErrors` collection.

Comment: I set a break point on `Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {grpcStatus}. Retry");` and is never fired.   `HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable` is listed in serverErrors

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have overseen that line ... What about the `resultPredicate` that function which is passed to the `HandleResult`?

Comment: What is the exception type which is thrown?

Comment: resultPredicate: put a breakpoint inside, never intercepted as well. The thrown exception type is Grpc.Core.RpcException: 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.Soc.

Comment: You can modify the `Policy` like this to trigger for `RpcException` as well: `Policy.Handle<RpcException>().OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(...)`

Comment: tried but w/o any success. It's as if `.AddPolicyHandler(retryFunc);` called on `AddGrpcClient` is not considered

Comment: Even if I put `Policy.Handle<Exception>()` it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, let's try to use the policy without the DI. The `retryFunc ` returns a policy on which you can call `ExecuteAsync`. 1) Create a `CountryServiceClient` instance manually 2) Call `retryFunc` like this: `var policy = retryFunc(emptyRequest);` 3) Call the `ExecuteAsync` like this: `await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.GetAllAsync(emptyRequest));`

Comment: @PeterCsala Tried your sugestion (and updated the question. Without DI.. it works. So could this be a bug in microsoft helper method .AddPolicyHandler(retryFunc);? Thanks

Comment: Awesome. I don't think there is a bug. There is a couple of overloads for `AddPolicyHandler`, maybe we are just using the wrong one. Could you please try to register your latest policy definition with `AddGrpcClient` and `AddPolicyHandler`? `services.AddGrpcClient<CountryServiceClient>(o => { ... }).AddPolicyHandler(policy);`

Comment: `services.AddGrpcClient<TestServiceClient>(o => { ...}).AddPolicyHandler(policy.AsAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>());` didn't work. Still not fired

Comment: Well that `AsAsyncPolicy` call is not a good idea here. Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: If your grpc service client's `TestAsync` returns an `HttpResponseMessage` then you should define your policy like this: `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<Exception>().RetryAsync(3, ...`

Comment: @PeterCsala still not working.. updated my question with Second attempt

Comment: I've checked out your solution and now I can see that the `TestAsync` returns with `AsyncUnaryCall<Empty>`. So, defining a policy for `HttpResponseMessage` will not help. The `AddPolicyHandler` expects a policy where the response type is `HttpResponseMessage`. So you can't register a policy which is defined like this: `Policy<AsyncUnaryCall<Empty>>.Handle<Exception>()...`. So according to my understanding you can't use `AddPolicyHandler` for grpc clients.

Comment: well, so the blog from which I copied is nonsense?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with grpc to judge. But based on my 5+ years of experience with Polly it tells me that either you miss a package which defines a new set of overloads for `IHttpClientBuilder` or they are incompatible.

Comment: to me his example worked with .net core 3. Then probably something has changed. Otherwise the blog would be full of complains :) Btw thank you very much for your support

Comment: I've just found [this twitter](https://twitter.com/jamesnk/status/1372280366669594624?lang=en). Would you be so kind and summarise in a post what have you tried and found while we were experimenting?

Comment: In a post? I don't have a blog..

Comment: Sorry, post as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not working for you because Retry is now built into Grpc. In order to make this work, register your service as follows:

```
var defaultMethodConfig = new MethodConfig
{
   Names = { MethodName.Default },
   RetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy
   {
       MaxAttempts = 3,
       InitialBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
       MaxBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
       BackoffMultiplier = 1,
       RetryableStatusCodes =
       {
           // Whatever status codes you want to look for
           StatusCode.Unauthenticated, StatusCode.NotFound, StatusCode.Unavailable,
       }
   }
  };
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddGrpcClient<TestServiceClient>(o => { 
      o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
      o.ChannelOptionsActions.Add(options =>
      {
          options.ServiceConfig = new ServiceConfig {MethodConfigs = {defaultMethodConfig}};
      });
  });
```

That will add the retry policy to your client. One other thing that you might run into. I didn't realize this at the time, but in my service implementation, I was setting up errors something like this:

```
var response = new MyServiceResponse()
// something bad happens
context.Status = new Status(StatusCode.Internal, "Something went wrong");
return response;
```

The retry logic will not kick in if you implement your service like that, you actually have to do something more like this:

```
// something bad happens
throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.Internal, "Something went wrong"));
```

The retry logic you configured when registering your client will then work. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @PeterCsala I tried some fix.

As a first attempt I tried without DependencyInjection, registering the policy as follows

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .RetryAsync(3, (exception, count) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request {count}, {exception.Message}. Retry");
    });

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient(channel);

await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.TestAsync(new Empty()));
```

This way it's working.

Then I came back to DI and used to register the policy as follows

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy = 
Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<Exception>().RetryAsync(3, (exception, count) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Request {count}, {exception.Exception.Message}. Retry");
});

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddGrpcClient<TestServiceClient>(o => { 
    o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
}).AddPolicyHandler(policy);

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var client = provider.GetRequiredService<TestServiceClient>();
    
var testClient = (await client.TestAsync(new Empty()));
```

And still not working.

At the end it seems AddPolicyHandler is not suitable for grpc clients?